# Apache 2 + PHP - Issue with .htaccess permissions

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I've created a apache2 environment to execute a PHP web application.

Almost everything is ok.

This is my app structure:

```
/var/www/html/
  - app/: PHP classes directory
  - views/: PHP templates directory
  - storage/: database and log stuffs directory
  - static/: public directory for js, css and images
  - index.php: Main script
  - .htaccess
```

Bellow the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule \.(static/)$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The redirect to index.php is working fine. I would like to allow access just to the directory static/ and deny and redirect any others requests to index.php.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+static/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,NC]

# remaining rules go here
```

Comment: This example does not fix the problem. =/

I still can call localhost/app/test.php

Comment: sorry man ... I was on vacations =)
When I tried to access app/test.php it shows the content of test.php. The redirect is not working.

Comment: Does `app/` folder also have a .htaccess? Can you show your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: The point is I dont want to create one .htaccess file for each directory I have in the application folders. Because I just need to allow access to /static folder and redirect everything else to /index.php

Comment: I am using Slim 3 and I tried another time and the redirect is working. But I think this is not the correct approach. Tks BTW

Comment: Rather than answering my queries you are incorrectly assuming that I am suggesting you to create separate .htaccess for each directory?

Comment: I understood your suggestion. I am telling you that this will not work properly because the redirect goes to index.php and Slim 3 interceptor tries to resolve the request of app/test.php and throws an exception. The .htaccess is right, but the approach I am using is wrong.

Comment: I need to use some hook in the Slim to handle requests when the route does not exists.

Comment: Try my updated rules and make sure these rules are your first rules.